# Null Reference Exception trying to add blank row to Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, radgridview, listcollectionview

Can someone please tell me why I keep getting a NULL reference exception when trying to perform the add below?  This only happens when the `ObservableCollection` is empty at the beginning.  If there is data in the collection from the start it works fine.

Load `ObservableCollection` and set collection `ViewSource`:

```
private void LoadCodeSets()
{
    this.codeSetData = new ObservableCollection<CodeSet>();

    var query = from c in context.CodeSets
                where c.LogicallyDeleted == 0
                orderby c.CodeSetID ascending
                select c;

    foreach (CodeSet c in query)
    {
        this.codeSetData.Add(c);
        this.codeSetView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(codeSetData);
        this.codeSetRadGridView.ItemsSource = this.codeSetView;
    }
}
```

Add New Record to Empty Data Grid

```
private void Add_CodeSet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        bool doesCodeSetExist = false;

        if (codeSetView == null)
        {

            codeSetView.AddNewItem(new CodeSet());
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (CodeSet cs in codeSetView)
            {
                if (cs.CodeSetID == 0)
                {
                    doesCodeSetExist = true;
                    this.lblMessages.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                    this.lblMessages.FontWeight = System.Windows.FontWeights.ExtraBold;
                    this.lblMessages.Content = "Please fill in new user form and click Save User.";
                    this.lblMessages.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
            if (!doesCodeSetExist)
            {
                CodeSet newCodeSet = new CodeSet();
                codeSetView.AddNewItem(newCodeSet);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Error.LogError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this block of code is causing the issue

```
if (codeSetView == null)
{
    codeSetView.AddNewItem(new CodeSet());
}
```

If `codeSetView` is `null` you cant use `codeSetView.AddNewItem`.
You will have to initiate `codeSetView` before adding items.

eg:

```
if (codeSetView == null)
{
    codeSetView = new ...... or (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(codeSetData);
    codeSetView.AddNewItem(new CodeSet());
}
```

Comment: This is true.  I need to figure out how I can default this somehow to init my collection and collection view source.  In the case where my linq query does not return any records.